# how miners within a mining pool execute transactions and verify blocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, mining, mining-pools

I know that solo miners have to select & execute transactions in a block and also verify the recipint block and its transactions, all by themself.

However, I am not sure how this works in a mining pool. Who execute transactions in a block? and how verify the recipint block and its transactions? Do miners within a pool collabarate with each other in executing transactions in a block and verifying transactions in the recipint block? (e.g., every miner is responsible for a set of transactions) or these tasks are only done by the manager of the mining pool, and miners only participate in the PoW consensus?

I would appreciate if there is a research paper that clearly say and answer those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pool manager is in charge of validating transactions and building a candidate block for the pool miners :

> Most mining pools are "managed," meaning that there is a company or individual running a pool server. The owner of the pool server is called the pool operator, and he charges pool miners a percentage fee of the earnings.
> The pool server runs specialized software and a pool-mining protocol that coordinate the activities of the pool miners. **The pool server is also connected to one or more full bitcoin nodes and has direct access to a full copy of the blockchain database.** **This allows the pool server to validate blocks and transactions on behalf of the pool miners**, relieving them of the burden of running a full node.

Miners are thus only involved in the resolution of the PoW algorithm by providing computing power to the pool :

> The pool server constructs a candidate block by aggregating transactions, adding a coinbase transaction (with extra nonce space), calculating the merkle root, and linking to the previous block hash. **The header of the candidate block is then sent to each of the pool miners as a template. Each pool miner then mines using the block template**, at a higher (easier) target than the bitcoin network target, and sends any successful results back to the pool server to earn shares.

The sources come from the book *Mastering Bitcoin*, chapter 10 about mining and consensus, that I strongly recommend you for more information on the subject : https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch10.asciidoc.

Of course this can be extended to Ethereum mining pools.